# How to omit "query string" from Firebase Functions CDN Cache?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cdn, firebase-hosting

Our system uses Firebase Functions (Https) to dynamically serve content which also has CDN Cache. Our use case does not require CDN to cache urls differently based on "Query string", and would be even more more optimized without query string. Is there a way to omit it?

This is the documentation for managing cache for Firebase, but it does not say anything about configuring the "query string":
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache

There is a documentation about omitting "query string" on gcp:
https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching

Comment: To be clear, are you using Firebase Hosting as a caching proxy in front of Cloud Functions?  Cloud Functions itself does not cache anything.

Comment: oh right, it's Firebase Hosting that does the caching. I was confused with Functions because there is also a way to config caching condition with Vary header in response.

Comment: Yeah, that header coming from the function is just instructing Hosting what to do with the response.